# How to get php logs on 1and1 hosting

Tags: php

I am hosting a web application on a 1and1 Basic plan.

I have tried setting up php error logging, by following [their instructions](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/enable-error-logs-a792503.html), and thus have set up `php.ini` as follows :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
log_errors = On 
display_errors = Off 
error_log = /homepages/31/d704704531/htdocs/logs/php-errors.log
```

However it is not working, the file is not being created, I don't see an error message anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the destination file is in the `logs` folder, which is read only.

This is silly, but one needs to point the logs to another destination, for example :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
log_errors = On 
display_errors = Off 
error_log = /homepages/31/d704704531/htdocs/mylogs/php-errors.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, that worked for me:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT;
log_errors = On;
display_errors = Off;
error_log = ./php-errors.log;
```

This will put the erro-logfile in the same folder where you put the php.ini,
I did that in the folder, where my custom php files are.